# Como configura phpmyadmin no linux?

Tags: linux, apache, phpmyadmin

Dei um `apt-get install phpmyadmin` e o linux fez a instalação na pasta `etc`; rodei no navegador `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` e deu erro 404. Mudei e joguei a pasta do phpmyadmin dentro do diretório `www`, mas ele apenas mostra a interface do Apache e a lista de arquvios da pasta. Não abre a interface do phpmyamind como no Windows. O que devo fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça o download e descompacte os arquivos no diretório onde deseja acessar.

Exemplo, caso queria acessar como `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`, entre na pasta do `DOCUMENT_ROOT` definido no `VirtualHost` do Apache. Então crie uma pasta como o nome que deseja "phpmyadmin". Descompacte tudo nessa pasta.

Feito isso, basta acessar `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` e configurar seguindo as instruções da tela.

obs: Estou considerando que o seu ambiente já esteja com Apache configurado e `http://localhost` acessível.

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, muito mesmo. Funcionou! Abs!

Answer (score 1):

By default, apt-get install phpmyadmin installs and create a file /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf.

Contents page is on /usr/share/phpmyadmin/

Take a look:

## /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf

```
# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration

Alias /dbo /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php

        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

                php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
                php_flag track_vars On
                php_flag register_globals Off
                php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
                php_value include_path .
                php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
                php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyad                                                                                                              min/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/
        </IfModule>

</Directory>

# Authorize for setup
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
    <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
    AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
    </IfModule>
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
```

Comment: Eu não encontrei esse arquivo

Comment: Como configuro isso?

Comment: Porque você não tenta antes: apt-get remove phpmyadmin e depois instala novamente. Normalmente é mais rápido.

Comment: Eu tentei `dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin` mas vou tentar como voce falou. To desesperado preciso configurar isso antes das 14hrs

Comment: Funcionou reinstalando?

Comment: Atualmente está na pasta `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Instalando usando o apt-get, em algumas versões do ubuntu/ubuntu server é necessário acrescentar diretamente o caminho do phpmyadmin no arquivo de configuração do apache, para isso digite no terminal:

```
vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

**Acrescente** uma última linha co parâmetro abaixo e salve o arquivo

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Depois reiniciar o apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Como você foi se inventar de mudar a pasta e tal, se não der certo, desinstala, instala e segue o que eu disse aí em cima. Outra forma também é instalar baixando o pacote em vez de usar o apt-get:

No terminal entre na sua pasta raiz do apache, geralmente a /var/www/ ou /var/www/html

Faça o download no arquivo em https://www.phpmyadmin.net/

```
wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.5.2/phpMyAdmin-4.5.2-all-languages.zip

unzip phpMyAdmin-4.5.2-all-languages.zip

mv phpMyAdmin-4.5.2-all-languages phpmyadmin
```

Pronto!  Acesse http://localhost/phpmyadmin.

*Lembre que a tela de login do phpmyadmin faz uma conexão com o mysql server. Caso seu password do mysql server esteja em branco, você precisa alterar o arquivo de configuração do phpMyAdmin para permitir logins com senhas em branco. Para isso vamos editeo arquivo:

```
vim /var/www/phpmyadmin/libraries/config.default.php
```

Ache a linha
**$cfg[‘Servers’][$i][‘AllowNoPassword’] = ”;**

Substitua por

**$cfg[‘Servers’][$i][‘AllowNoPassword’] = ‘true’;**

Salve e feche o arquivo. Pronto!